# Sides of a Triangle (or Right Triangle)

Tags: c

```
float a, b, c;

printf( "Enter three nonzero values:\n" );
scanf( "%f%f%f", &a, &b, &c );
```

When I input a = 2, b = 2, and c = 4, why does...

```
    if( a < ( b + c )) 
    {
        if( b < ( a + c )) 
        {
            if( c < ( a + b )) 
            {
                printf( "This is a triangle." );
            }
            else 
            {
                printf( "This is not a triangle." );            
            }   
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

...print "This is not a triangle" but...

```
    if( a < ( b + c )) 
    {
        if( b < ( a + c )) 
        {
            if( c < ( a + b )) 
            {
                printf( "This is a triangle." );                
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        printf( "This is not a triangle." );            
    }
```

...does not? A solution I am looking at uses the latter code. However, the line where "This is not a triangle" should be is just blank in my command propt when I run the program.

I am using notepad++ with Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019.

**vvvvvvv SOLVED vvvvvvvv**

This is how I solved the exercise if anyone at the same learning stage as me is interested. I am using a book to learn c programming and I've only read three chapters. Therefore, I wanted to use only what I have learned from the first three chapters.

```
float a, b, c, temp, no = 0, count = 1;


printf( "Enter three nonzero values:\n" );
scanf( "%f%f%f", &a, &b, &c );

while ( count < 3 ) {
    if(a + b > c){

        /* Switch place of a and b */

        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;

        /* Switch place of b and c */

        temp = c;
        c = b;
        b = temp;

        count++;
    }
    else {
        no++;

        /* Switch place of a and b */

        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;

        /* Switch place of b and c */

        temp = c;
        c = b;
        b = temp;

        count++;
    }
}

if ( no > 0 ) {
    printf ( "This is not a valid triangle." );
}
else {
    printf ( "This is a valid triangle." );
}

return 0;
```

This solution uses a while loop to determine if the sides of a triangle can be a valid triangle. I use variable temp to switch places of the sides and then add one to variable no if one of the combinations is not a valid triangle.

I also want to add that the solution for this exercise on chegg.com is false. It confused me a lot.

**vvvvvvvv ANOTHER SOLUTION vvvvvvv**

The next exercise in my book was to calculate if three values could be the sides of a right triangle. When I solved this I realized that the same code could be used for a regular triangle, too.

```
float a, b, largest, temp;


printf( "Enter three nonzero values:\n" );
scanf( "%f%f%f", &largest, &a , &b );


if ( a > largest ) {
    temp = largest;
    largest = a;
    a = temp;
}

if ( b > largest ) {
    temp = largest;
    largest = b;
    b = temp;
}
/* a + b > largest if it's a regular triangle */
if ( a * a + b * b == largest * largest ) {
    printf( "This is a valid right triangle" );
}
else {
    printf( "This is not a valid right triangle" );
}

return 0;
```

So instead of looping, just compare the variables a and b with largest to find out which variable is largest. And then use the pythagorean theorem to find out if the sides can represent a right triangle, or the a + b > c if the it is a regular triangle.

I prefer this way rather than using unnecessary looping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because this is false: `if( c < ( a + b ))` since `4 < (2 + 2)` is false. Therefore the `else` branch will executes. In your second variant it will only print "This is not a triangle." when the first `if` is false otherwise not. Try this

```
if ( (a < ( b + c )) && (b < ( a + c )) && (c < ( a + b )) )
  printf( "This is a triangle.");
else
  printf( "This is not a triangle.");
```

Note: This would also print `"This is not a triangle."` since by your logic with those values it is not a triangle anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a bracket

```
  if( c < ( a + b )) 
    {
        printf( "This is a triangle." );

        }else {
            printf( "This is not a triangle." );

        }
```

If wasn't closed before else

Comment: Remove one brace after closing else

Comment: Then the compiler would have reported an error: "else without matching if".

Answer (score 0):

Notice the curly brackets and indentation.

In the 1st example:

```
if(...)
    if(...)
        if( c < ( a + b )) 
        {
            printf( "This is a triangle." );
        }
        else 
        {
            printf( "This is not a triangle." );            
        }
```

In order to get to the third `if` statement, the previous two `if`s (the first **AND** the second `if`) have to be true. Our third `if` statement has an `else` branch, which will execute if the third condition is false.

In the 2nd example:

```
if( a < ( b + c )) 
{
    // some more code
}
else 
{
    printf( "This is not a triangle." );            
}
```

`else` branch will execute only if the first condition is false. If the first condition is true, this `else` will never be executed.

---

That being said, the first example translates to:

> **If** `a` is less than `b+c` **AND** `b` is less than `a+c` **AND** `c` is less than `a+b`
>
> **Then** *this is a triangle*
>
> **Else** *this is not a triangle*

The second example translates to:

> **If** `a` is less than `b+c`
>
> **Then** check other conditions
>
> **Else** *this is not a triangle*

---

As a side note, be careful when [comparing](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) `float` numbers